# fixing a memory leak in a windows dll

Tags: c++, string, dll, mfc

Inherited some code that looks like c++ or .Net?  This is not in my wheelhouse.  Anyway it has a memory leak by using heap memory and then reassigning local memory over and over:

```
CPTRecord* pRec = static_cast<CPTRecord*>(pData);

// Remove channel # from end of test name
CString testName = pRec->m_stdf.test_txt;

int strIndex = testName.ReverseFind(' ');
if (strIndex != -1)
{
    testName.Delete(strIndex,9);
    pRec->m_stdf.test_txt = (char *)LPCTSTR(testName);
    pRec->m_stdf.test_txt_size = testName.GetLength();
}
```

I am not sure how to cast the pointer, or use `memcpy` instead of assigning using `(char *)LPCTSTR`

Comment: That is C++ FYI.  Where do you think there is a leak here?  if `test_text` was allocated dynamically then just `delete []` it before assigning a new value.  Better yet; use `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) and create `LPCTSTR`'s only when needed.  Also, this is C++, so there aren't many good reasons to use `malloc` and `free`

Comment: LPCTSTR is actually a Windows API construct.  It stands for (roughly) "long pointer to constant T-string".  Note that T-strings can be built of either char or wchar_t, depending on compiler flags (see Windows and Unicode support).  So, casting to a char* is extremely unsafe from the get-go, since it might be a wchar_t in a different build.  For the same reason, constructing an LPCTSTR from a CString is suspect.

[This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be helpful.

Comment: This as all kinds of wrong written all over it. Ironically, there is no memory leak in *this* snippet. The only dynamic allocation of any kind is happning inside a CString and it is scope-protected. But there is *plenty* wrong with what this code *is* doing. I'd start with that.

Comment: WhozCraig - that does not really help.  What would you change and why?